# creating API to do calculations in backed using DRF

Tags: django, api, django-rest-framework

This question might be simple, but I like to know the proper way of doing this.

I want to create some APIs that lets end user to send a string to the backed, and backend does some calculations to extract entities, and returns Jason response containing a dictionary of these entities.

So in this process, I really don't need any model, any serialization and as the result no CRUD happens in my views.

I can use normal Django in my view to render Json response using:

```
return JsonResponse(dic)
```

Also my input is currently entered in a Django form.

so my question is that:

1- what would be the correct url pattern if i don't use django form. How should I retrieve string in my view based on this pattern.

2- can I use DRF here or **return JsonResponse(dic)** is efficient enough,

Thanks

Comment: If you are using POST request in the template, you can retrieve data with `request.POST`

Comment: so what would be the url pattern?